# how to refresh component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, use-state

I use React js ,There is a variable in the `App.js` file called `Persons`.
I want the `Persons` value to be updated every time I click on the button.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import EleventHeaderCard from "./ElevatedHeaderCard";
import axios from "axios";

export let persons = [
  {
    id: 9,
    email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Michael",
    last_name: "Lawson",
    avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/follettkyle/128.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    email: "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Lindsay",
    last_name: "Ferguson",
    avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/araa3185/128.jpg"
  }
];

const handleClick = () => {
  return axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`).then(res => {
    persons = res.data.data;
    console.log(persons);
  });
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button color="primary" type="Submit" onClick={handleClick}>
        click me !!!
      </Button>
      <EleventHeaderCard />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here you can see my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-glitter-icbz5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Use the state: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @Treycos If possible, edit the codeSandbox for me. I can't understand

Comment: @yaser.barati see below answer

Comment: @SpringerF tnx :)))

Comment: @yaser.barati you're welocme :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic used to pass data into subComponent is wrong you have to pass it as props instead of import inside subComponent

Also in order to rerender every request you have to use the [useState](http://%20reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook , which returns an array of yourValue and it's setter method

so use inside the app function

```
let [persons, setPersons] = useState(initialData);
```

and then in the axios result set the persons using `setPersons` funciton

and in your `EleventHeaderCard`  coponent pass the person as props .

see this [working pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-minsky-h1vjv)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). It will re-render the component on change.

```
const initialValue = [
{
  id: 9,
  email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
  first_name: "Michael",
  last_name: "Lawson",
  avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/follettkyle/128.jpg"
},
{
  id: 10,
  email: "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
  first_name: "Lindsay",
  last_name: "Ferguson",
  avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/araa3185/128.jpg"
}
];

export default function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleClick = () => {
    return axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`).then(res => {
      setPeople(res.data.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button color="primary" type="Submit" onClick={handleClick}>
      click me !!!
    </Button>
    <EleventHeaderCard />
  </div>
  );
}
```